# Does the unchecked { ... } block apply only to the current function?

Tags: math, solidity-0.8.x

Take the following code snippet:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract MyContract {
    function foo() public returns (uint256 result) {
        // do unsafe work
    }

    function bar() public returns (uint256 result) {
        unchecked {
            uint256 foo_value = foo();
            // do safe work
        }
    }
```

Does the `unchecked` block in the `bar` function disable the safety checks in the `foo` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for Solidity 0.8.0 it doesn't seem so like the `unchecked` block in `bar` disables the safety checks in `foo`..

> The setting only affects the statements that are syntactically inside the block. Functions called from within an unchecked block do not inherit the property.

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/control-structures.html#checked-or-unchecked-arithmetic

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it only applies to current block:

```
pragma solidity v0.8.9;

contract Test {
function unsafe_subtract(uint a, uint b) pure public returns (uint) {
    unchecked {
      return subtract(a,b);
    }
  }

  function subtract(uint a, uint b) pure public returns (uint) {
    return a - b;
  }
}
```

Calling `unsafe_subtract(1, 100)` reverted.